# material-ui autocomplete attribute "value" not available when it is used with attribute "getOptionLabel"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

```html
            <Autocomplete
                id="license-select"
                options={licReqList}
                value = {licReqList[0] ? licReqList[0].licReqStr : null}
                getOptionLabel={(option) => option.licReqStr}
                onChange={handleLicReqStrChange}
                style={{ width: 600, marginBottom:"30px" }}
                size="small"
                disablePortal={true}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" />}
            />
```

in this code, when licReqList includes some objects, I want my autocomplete box to select the first value (licReqList[0]) by default and to show its string value (licReqList[0].licReqStr). I think my value attribute should do that, but when I try it, I got the following error:

"The `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for {licReqList[0].licReqStr}."

Could anyone tell me how I can deal with this error?

Here is the type of the variables for clarification:

licReqList: [Objects{..., licReqStr : String}]

Answer (score 0):

Your values are objects and thus you need to assign an object to the `value` prop:

```js
value={licReqList[0] ? licReqList[0] : null}
```

or shorter:

```js
value={licReqList[0] ?? null}
```

if you are not using `multiple` I think you can get away with passing in `undefined` also:

```js
value={licReqList[0]}
```

`getOptionLabel` will take care of displaying the `licReqStr` property of this particular value and all other options.